# A HTML Extraction API using RegEx or HTML Parser

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing, html-parser

I am aware that it is public opinion to *not* use `RegEx` for *parsing* `HTML`; however I do not see how it would be harmful to use `RegEx` (alike functions have been added in previous `Scripting Languages` using `RegEx` such as `_StringBetween( )` in `AutoIt3`) for what I want to achieve.

I am also aware that `_StringBetween( )` was not *specifically* written for `HTML` but I have been using it without any problem on `HTML` content for the past 8 years along with other folks.

For my `HTML Extraction API` I would like to present the following piece of `HTML`

```
<div class="video" id="video-91519"><!-- The value of the identifier is dynamic-->
  <a href="about:blank"><img src="silly.jpg"><!-- So is the href and src in a, img -->
</div>
```

The reason for the `API` I am trying to write is to make extraction of the `video_url` and `thumbnail` extremely easy and therefore a `HTML parser` seems out of reach. I would like to be able to extract it using something amongst the lines of

```
<div class="video" id="video-{{unknown}}">{{unknown}}<a href="{{video_url}}"><img src="{{thumbnail}}">{{unknown}}</div>
```

Of course, in the previous piece of `HTML` you could do it much easier such as

```
<a href="{{video_url}}"><img src="{{thumbnail}}">
```

but I was trying to present a *perfect* example to avoid confusion.

*How does `RegEx` come into play?* Well, I was going to replace `{{video_url}}`, `{{thumbnail}}` and `{{unknown}}` with `(.*?)`, `(.*?)` and `.*` using `/s` and of course making sure that there are no multiple occurences of `{{video_url}}` and `{{thumbnail}}` in the provided input (not the `HTML`).

So, is there any reason for me not to use `RegEx` or still go for a `HTML parser` incl. proof of concepts of either acceptable `RegEx` and/ or using a `HTML parser`? I cannot *personally* see how to make this happen using a `HTML parser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you have framed the problem pre-supposes the solution: if you want to be able to specify a pattern to match, then you have to use a pattern-matching language, such as regex. But if you frame the question as allowing searches for content in the document, then other options might be available, such as a path-based input that compiled to XPath expressions, or CSS selectors as used very successfully by the likes of jQuery.

What you are building here is not really an *HTML extraction API* as such, but a *regex processing API* - you are inventing a simplified pattern-matching language which can be compiled to a regex, and that regex applied to any string.

That in itself is not a bad thing, but if the *users* of that pattern-matching API try to use it to parse a more complex or unpredictable document, they will have all the same problems that everyone has when they try to match HTML using regexes, plus additional limitations imposed by your pre-processor. Those limitations are an inevitable consequence of simplifying the language: you are trading some of the power of the regex engine in order to make your patterns more "user friendly".

To return to the idea of reframing the question, here is an example of a simplified matching API that could compile to CSS expressions (e.g. used with [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)):

```
 Find: div (class:video)
 Must-Contain: a, img
 Match: id Against video-{{video_id}}
 Child: a
     Extract: href Into video_url
 Child: img
     Extract: src Into thumbnail
```

Note that this language is a lot more abstracted away from the HTML; this has advantages and disadvantages. On the one hand, the simple matching pattern in your question is easy to create based on a single example. On the other hand, it is much more fragile to variations in the HTML, either due to changes in the site, or in-page variations such as adding an extra CSS class of "featured-video" to a small number of videos. The selector-based example requires the user to learn more specifics of the API, but if they don't know HTML and pattern-matching to begin with, a verbose syntax may be more helpful to them than one involving lots of cryptic punctuation.

Comment: The _users_ of the API will have little knowledge about pattern-matching and HTML. It is meant to be extremely simple to use and the documents _we_ are aiming to perform these tasks on are far from complex or unpredictable. Henche, me looking for a system that would make pattern-matching extremely easy and user-friendly. Maybe, eventually I will get rid of pattern matching completely and have my `app` figure out what to _extract_ based on a thumbnail and link. I just wanted to make sure it was not incredibly stupid and if there were better alternatives for achieving the same goal =)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time. Do you think given the statements in my other comment; that this will be an appropriate solution (RegEx) or would you still recommend your suggestion/example?

Comment: In the end the decision is up to you, but it's important to realise that there are genuine limitations to the approach, and it is not just prejudice that makes people avoid regexes for general-purpose HTML extraction. Perhaps don't spend too long refining this part of the code initially, knowing that either it will carry on working with the existing simple patterns, or will need replacing with a completely different approach.

Comment: Incidentally, one particular limitation of your proposed regex I haven't mentioned is that it's easy for even a non-greedy `.*?` to end up consuming a chunk of document if it finds something that looks like the start of the pattern but isn't immediately followed by what's expected. As long as your source documents are very predictable, it will probably be obvious straight away whether this is going to happen or not, but it's another reason this approach won't be scalable/robust.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. It is however quite insulting that people assume that _someone_ would _not_ understand that you cannot do the same thing with an unpredictable/complex document. I was indeed not going to refine this too much as it is only to develop modules more rapidly. I just assumed that maybe there were reasons I was _not_ aware of for avoid the use of `RegEx`. Thank you a lot for clarification!

Comment: Since we can't know everything you are and are not aware of, we can't account for it when answering. All we can do is look at your question, and highlight *all* limitations which you haven't mentioned, *in case you weren't aware of them*. The key to getting good answers is always to think about how you are asking the question. As I say above, your question pre-supposed the use of pattern-matching; it also came across quite defensive of your own idea. If instead you started with the problem you are solving, and asked for solutions with pros and cons, you might have had a more positive response.